# Which drywall edges to overlap

Tags: drywall

I had a door and frame that's been removed.  I then cut out a "box" if you will into the opening. I need to drywall the edges around this opening. The width is about 3-4" (the width of an inside door)

What is the right way to overlap my cuts of drywall for the inside and outside corners? (Or does it even matter?) I've tried to demonstrate the edges in the crude drawing below. The one on the left for example has the left side edge going up further and the horizontal piece butts up to it vs the right picture where the horizontal piece has the overlap edge and the vertical piece butts up to it

[image]

Comment: It doesn't matter for the walls, although it is standard practice to put drywall on the ceiling first so that the edges rest on the top edge of the drywall that you apply to the walls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't matter a bit.

The main time you need to think about how corners work is when the backing studs are different width. (If, for instance, you only have 1" of stud to attach to on one side of a corner, and 3-1/2" on the other side of the corner, you'll want to have the drywall sitting fully on that inch.)

Comment: Yes indeed, if your using say 5/8" firecode sheetrock and already laid the perpendicular sheet in, then your covering 5/8" of that 1" leaving only 3/8" (or less) of wood to screw or nail the sheet into.  That is way to close to the sheets edge. Small width stud first.

Comment: Right now the entire opening has been "boxed" with studs and all the existing drywall comes up flush to the studs. I was thinking I just need to anchor into the studs and finish the corners

Comment: I like using metal edge for the protruding corner you have this will hold up better than tape [like this](http://m.lowes.com/pd/SHEETROCK-Brand-8-ft-Corner-Bead/3018438?cm_mmc=SCE_PLA-_-LumberAndBuildingMaterials-_-GypsumAccessories-_-3018438:SHEETROCK_Brand&CAWELAID=&kpid=3018438&CAGPSPN=pla&store_code=2940&k_clickID=ea985018-4ea8-457c-a30f-c94373a534b8). Apply with mud like normal tape for inside corners I just use a folded piece of tape but there are corners for this also but I don't think that they are needed. +